# get only month from date in sqlite database

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a data base with a date column and i want to retrieve items that have an specific month in the date field. I've tried something like this.

The date field is in dd/mm/yyyy format

```
var = '09'
with conn:
    c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM sales WHERE strftime('%m',date) = '{var}'")
    x = c.fetchall()
```

Ive also tried

```
SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date('%m',date) = '{var}'
```

in every case i keep getting no errors but `x` is empty

note = i'll worry of injections after it works and there are several items in my database that match the "month = 09" criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `strftime()` only with the format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`, so either you should change the format of your dates or use the function `SUBSTR()` to get the month:

```
c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM sales WHERE substr(date, 4, 2) = '{var}'")
```

if you pass `var` padded with `'0'` at the left (if needed), so the comparison is alphabetical,
or:

```
c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM sales WHERE substr(date, 4, 2) + 0 = {var}")
```

so the comparison will be numerical.

In any case it is safer to write the code like this:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM sales WHERE substr(date, 4, 2) + 0 = ?", (var,))
```

where `var` is an integer variable, 
or:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM sales WHERE substr(date, 4, 2) = ?", (var,))
```

where `var` is a string variable padded with `'0'` at the left (if needed) like your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I changed the date format to YYYY-MM-DD and still had no luck, but solved it with the 'substr' function, as you recommended. I still would like to know why `strftime('%m',date) = '{var}'")` isnt working

Comment: `strftime()` works only when the date format is 'YYYY-MM-DD' as you can see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a78da65ead32a35bf6b49f9aed735fa4 and it reurns a string like `'05'`, not a number. So if `var` is defined like in your code `var = '09'` then it should work. Are you sure that you changed to the correct format?